# excluding null, tag from list in XPath

Tags: html, xpath

I want to get the information using XPath.

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color:red;">
            <p>Detail</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Title 1</th>
        <td style="border: 1px solid blue;">AAA</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid blue;">LIST.AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Title 2</th>
        <td style="border: 1px solid blue;">BBB</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid blue;">LIST.BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Title 3</th>
        <td style="border: 1px solid blue;">CCC</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid blue;">apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Title 4</th>
        <td style="border: 1px solid blue;">DDD</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid blue;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>etc</th>
        <td style="width:40%;">test</td>
     <td style="border: 1px solid blue;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

1. `th` contains the string 'Title' / ('tr' with entries with 'title' in 'th')
2. `td[2]` must have '.' (dot)
3. Exclude if `td[2]` has a string 'apple'
4. Exclude if `td[2]` has a white space

i try:

```
node = table_html.xpath('//*[@class="table"]/tr[(contains(child::th, \'Title\'))]')]

    td1 = node.xpath('child::td[@style="border: 1px solid blue;"][1]/text()')

    td2 = node.xpath('child::td[@style="border: 1px solid blue;"][2]/text()[not(contains(text(), \'\'))]')
    td2 = node.xpath('child::td[@style="border: 1px solid blue;"][2]/text()[. != \'\']')
    td2 = node.xpath('child::td[@style="border: 1px solid blue;"][2]/text()[(. != \'\')]')

    etc...
```

the output i want:

```
td[1] /  td[2]
 AAA  / LIST_AAA
 BBB  / LIST_BBB
```

but the actual output is:

```
td[1] /  td[2]
 AAA  / LIST_AAA
 BBB  / LIST_BBB
 CCC  / trash
 DDD  /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you can use.

**xpath for td[1]:**

```
//table[@class='table']//tr[th[contains(.,'Title')]][td[2][contains(.,'.')][not(contains(.,'apple'))][string-length(.)>0]]/td[1]
```

**xpath for td[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rRCN.png):**

```
//table[@class='table']//tr[th[contains(.,'Title')]][td[2][contains(.,'.')][not(contains(.,'apple'))][string-length(.)>0]]/td[2]
```

**Chrome Dev Tools Screenshot:**
[image]

**Single xpath with 2 output:**

```
 //table[@class='table']//tr[th[contains(.,'Title')]][td[2][contains(.,'.')][not(contains(.,'apple'))][string-length(.)>0]]/concat(./td[1]/text(),"/",./td[2]/text())
```

[image]

Comment: This is the perfect answer I wanted. Thank you very much for your Answer ❤️